# Jacobians for arithmetic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

We know that the Jacobian of an algebraic curve play an important role in the study of curves. My question is: Is there a "Jacobian" for an arithmetic curve such as $Spec Z$, which parameterizes some special objects on this curve. I am not an expert. Maybe my question is trivial.

Comment: Of course, there is the class group. This can be extended to the Arakelov Picard group. See Szpiro's article in Astérisque 127 or Neukirch's book on Algebraic Number Theory.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me more details?